# Some USB 3.1 ports only working as USB 2.0

Tags: windows, usb, motherboard, usb-c

I have a Gigabyte B650i Aorus (1.0 rev) running a 7800x3D. When I connect a USB 3.0/1/2 device to the rear USB C 3.1 port (labelled as DP/USB3.1), or the front panel USB C port, I noticed it can only reach 2.0 speeds. I've tried everything I can think of to fix the issue: BIOS update, chipset/cpu driver update, clean Windows install, modifying all 4 USB settings in the advanced BIOS options in all permutations, using USB deview to uninstall all USB devices. Obviously I've also checked that these devices and cables work correctly on other computers.

HWInfo shows that the ports that aren't working are on the same AMD 3.1 extensible host controller. It shows that the drives support higher versions of USB, but are "connected to a USB 2.00 port" (see the Samsung SSD device in attached screenshot).
Weirdly, the controller also has another device connected to it which doesn't correspond to any of my plugged in devices (see the "Giga-Byte" device in the other HWInfo screenshot). This device is listed as only being compatible with USB 2.0. I've read that sometimes (always?) when you have a 2.0 USB device connected to a hub, it forces the rest of the devices to run at 2.0 as well-- could this device be causing some kind of issue?

Upon investigating every single device in the device manager, I was able to find a "USB Composite Device" that has a matching VID and PID with the mystery device. On USB deview, that same VID and PID was associated with a Realtek USB audio device. I uninstalled realtek and DTS:X, turned off high-def audio and integrated graphics in the bios, uninstalled those devices and still the "Giga-Byte" device shows up in HWInfo. So I can't get rid of it, but I'm not even sure if that's what's causing my problems anyway.

It may also be relevant that when usb 3.x devices are plugged in to USB-A ports on other extensible host controllers, I can only get up to "3.0 SuperSpeed" despite the devices supporting 3.1, but at least they're not stuck on 2.0.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

[image: HWinfo Screenshot 1]

[image: HWinfo Screenshot 2]

Comment: I don't do windows, however, a driver from 2006 does not look good. Secondly, you are not saying whether the devices are directly connected, or whether they are using an extension lead or pigtail.

Comment: @Bib - USB drivers rarely change. USB 2 and USB 3 are built into Windows 10. The authors problem isn’t a driver problem

Comment: Could it be an integrated web cam?  Maybe part of your monitor?